# Explicitly close a connection established by LWP::Simple

Tags: perl, tcp, lwp

I have a Perl script that uses `getprint` from
[`LWP::Simple`](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::Simple)
to fetch some JSON data.

We're seeing lingering TCP connections remaining open on both servers.

I want to make sure that Perl is explicitly closing the connection when `getprint` completes. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Edited - I'm pretty new to web server communication.  The script just queries special URL, that URL contains something like "?serial=59595" which I thought was a "POST".

Comment: No, in fact, POST requests tend to not have url params.

Comment: while LWP::UserAgent (used by LWP::Simple::getprint) does allow keep_alive or a connection cache, it shouldn't be happening by default

Answer (score 0):

Though it has been pointed out LWP::Simple should not be keeping the connection open unasked, I would suggest to use [LWP::UserAgent](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent). You can then simply let the object run out of scope:

```
{
    # Set the timeout to some value you find reasonable
    my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new( timeout => 30 );
    # open connection, do what you wanted to use it for
    # ...
    # will run out of scope now. This may not be necessary,
    # but now you can be quite certain the connection is dropped.

}
```

The oo-interface also allows for (imo) simpler configuration of things like timeout etc.